# Why does CreateFile return invalid handle?

Tags: c++, winapi, file-management

I have `CreateFile()` to create a hidden file type but the problem that it keeps returning invalid handle.

```
file = CreateFileW(_T("hey.txt"),
                   GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS,
                   0, 0);
error = GetLastError();
WriteFile(file, buff, sizeof(buff),
          &dwRet, NULL);
```

Any idea?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in your code. What is the error reported by `GetLastError()` (if there's one)? How do you know `file` is an invalid handle? Moreover, this code doesn't create a hidden file.

Comment: Well i used the GetLastError() and I got "Failed with error 6: invalid handle"

Comment: Are you sure that is the error after CreateFileW, and not the error after WriteFile? You don't include a path for `hey.txt`, maybe you don't have write access in the location you are using. And there is no need to use CreateFileW, CreateFile would be fine too.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have access to it.  Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would probably be best if you showed the exact code that you're using including all the error checking, and how you do it, is important (especially in the case of this question)...

The correct error checking for your code should be something more like...

```
file = CreateFile(_T("hey.txt"), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, 0);

if (file == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
   const DWORD error = GetLastError();

   // Do something!
}
else
{  
   if (!WriteFile(file, buff, sizeof(buff), &dwRet, NULL))
   {
      const DWORD error = GetLastError();

      // Do something!
   }
}
```

You should only be checking for an error if you get a return value of `INVALID_FILE_HANDLE` as `CreateFile()` might not reset the last error before it starts and so you might get spurious error values from `GetLastError()` if the function succeeds...

A last error of 6, `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`, is unusual from `CreateFile()` unless you're using the template file parameter, which you're not...

Your code using `CreateFileW` and _T("") is incorrect and wont compile in a non unicode build. Better to use `CreateFile` and _T("") or `CreateFileW` and L"".

Your code will not create a hidden file, see molbdnilo's answer.

Answer (score 3):

`0` is not a valid parameter for `dwFlagsAndAttributes`. To create a hidden file, pass `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN`.

Comment: how about you tell us the numeric value of file after the call to CreateFile and also what GetLastError returns immediately following CreateFile.

Answer (score 0):

If "C:\test.txt" exists **and** is hidden, then following code fails (h = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) :

```
h = CreateFile("C:\\test.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, 0, 0);
```

this fails too (argument 6 == FILE_ATTRIBUTES_NORMAL or argument6 == 0 seems so be the same) :

```
h = CreateFile("C:\\test.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
```

but this works :

```
h = CreateFile("C:\\test.txt", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN, 0);
```

So roughly in other words :
if the file already exists and is hidden then CreateFile with "CREATE_ALWAYS" fails if argument 6 != FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN.

Comment: BTW: The online documentation of CreateFile states this:
Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP: If CREATE_ALWAYS and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL are specified, CreateFile fails and sets the last error to ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED if the file exists and has the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN or FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM attribute. To avoid the error, specify the same attributes as the existing file.