# How can I write to a named pipe in Windows using js-ctypes?

Tags: firefox, jsctypes

I am able to connect to the pipe (I can see the connection), but WriteFile always yields a result of 0 and bytesWritten is 0. What is going on?

```
  let pipeName = "\\\\.\\pipe\\xxx.pipe";
  let hFile = createFile(pipeName, pipeMode, 0, null, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, null);
  let hFileInt = ctypes.cast(hFile, ctypes.intptr_t);
  if (ctypes.Int64.compare(hFileInt.value, INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) == 0) {
    throw new Error("CreateFile failed for " + pipeName + ", error " +
                 ctypes.winLastError);
  }

  let bytesWritten = ctypes.uint32_t(88);
  let msg = "hello world\n";
  let result = writeFile(hFile, msg, 12, bytesWritten.address(), null);
  result = flushFileBuffer(hFile);
```

the result of writeFile is 0 as is flushFileBuffer, and bytesWritten changes from 88 to 0. :( Here are the declarations:

```
  let writeFile = kernel32.declare(
    "WriteFile",
    ctypes.winapi_abi,
    ctypes.int32_t,     //bool  // return type: 1 indicates success, 0 failure
    ctypes.voidptr_t,   // in: hObject
    ctypes.jschar.ptr,  // in: lpBuffer
    ctypes.uint32_t,    // in: nNumberOfBytesToWrite
    ctypes.uint32_t.ptr,    // out: lpNumberOfBytesWritten
    ctypes.voidptr_t.ptr    // inout: lpOverlapped
  );  

  let flushFileBuffer = kernel32.declare(
    "FlushFileBuffers",
    ctypes.winapi_abi,
    ctypes.int32_t,     //bool  // return type: 1 indicates success, 0 failure
    ctypes.voidptr_t    // in: hObject
  );
```

**Update.** I changed pipeMode to GENERIC_WRITE and got a successful write. But this is confusing. I have

```
  var GENERIC_READ = ctypes.uint32_t(0x80000000);
  var GENERIC_WRITE = ctypes.uint32_t(0x40000000);
```

and

```
let pipeMode = GENERIC_WRITE;
```

but

```
let pipeMode = GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE;
```

doesn't. Why doesn't it work? Am I doing the bitwise comparison wrong?

**Update 2.** pipeMode is fixed using >>> 0

```
  var GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
  var GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
  let pipeMode = ctypes.uint32_t((GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE) >>> 0);
```

However, it does not look like the pipe is written to (even with flush) until I close using

```
  closeHandle(hFile);
```

and when the handle is closed, my receiving application gets the message, but it is strange. From my C# app, I see

```
h\0e\0l\0l\0l\0o \0
```

**Update 3.** From the C# line, I was waiting for a whole line, so waiting for the \n. I increased the buffer length to 24 and it now triggers at the right time. The only remaining problem (for this question) is why I get \0 after each letter.

**Update 4.** This is probably the problem

jschar  A 16-bit unsigned character. This is different from uint16_t in that C jschar values are automatically converted into 1-character JavaScript strings. These are Unicode characters.

I just want a regular character.

**Update 5.** Yup that's it. Changing to

```
ctypes.char.ptr,  // in: lpBuffer
```

makes it work. Or we should account for the 16-byte char on the other side.

Comment: Pipes are something I've been meaning to work on for awhile now. I'll take a look and get back to you tonight.

Comment: The pipes are working now with either GENERIC_READ or GENERIC_WRITE - I think there is something wrong with my bitwise operation.

Comment: Is your full code up on github somewhere?

Comment: For `CreateFile` your `dwFlagsAndAttributes` value is `0` is this allowed?

Comment: yeah, no problem with that

Comment: I have it in a Bitbucket repo - will check how I can share tomorrow.

Comment: Cool looks like its working. However they say a value of `0` is not valid - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5926101/1828637

Comment: I think I need your help now haha, do you know why I keep getting invalid handle when I try to write/read from pipes - https://github.com/Noitidart/jsc-pipes/blob/master/modules/pipe/PipeWorker.js#L332-L362 - you can install this addon and then open up `chrome://jsc-pipes/content/pages/gui.xhtml` and play with it if you like - it looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/SJ0pE6j.png

Comment: I don't know why but when I try `CreateFile` with `dwCreationDisposition` as `CREATE_NEW`, it keeps giving me the error `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` which is mind boggling because it obviously will not be found, it doesn't exist, I want it to make it. Do you know what's up?

Comment: Ahh, you cannot CREATE_NEW the pipe with CreateFile, you would have to used CreateNamedPIpe and that would become the named pipe server. In a different program I call CreateNamedPipe and from javascript I call CreateFile OPEN_EXISTING.

Comment: @Noitidart do you have a bitbucket username?

Comment: @Noitidart - readFile - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031573/using-js-ctypes-how-do-i-retrieve-output-from-windows-readfile

Comment: Thanks very much for that info on `CreateNamedPipe`! I'll update it to that tomorrow. I checked out that readfile and looks like you got it! i'm like that too, as I explain my question on stackoverflow I solve it eventually haha, even though I ask I keep working on it. :) Nice work! :) You should put your answer for this question in the solution it's nice to see all questions answered in a section :P

Comment: do you have some code you can sho where you do the `CreateNamedPipe`? I am setting up a file watcher. Main thread creates a pipe, and a child thread is the poller. I want the poller to break when I send a message on the pipe. Any code you could share would help tons, thanks!