# Using js-ctypes, how do I retrieve output from Windows ReadFile?

Tags: javascript, firefox, jsctypes

I'm using (while not being quite sure about lpBuffer -> char.ptr)

```
  let readFile = kernel32.declare(
    "ReadFile",
    ctypes.winapi_abi,
    ctypes.int32_t,     //bool  // return type: 1 indicates success, 0 failure
    ctypes.voidptr_t,   // in: hObject
    ctypes.char.ptr,  // out: lpBuffer
    ctypes.uint32_t,    // in: lpNumberOfBytesRead
    ctypes.uint32_t.ptr,    // out: lpNumberOfBytesWritten
    ctypes.voidptr_t.ptr    // inout: lpOverlapped
  );
```

for

```
BOOL WINAPI ReadFile(
  _In_        HANDLE       hFile,
  _Out_       LPVOID       lpBuffer,
  _In_        DWORD        nNumberOfBytesToRead,
  _Out_opt_   LPDWORD      lpNumberOfBytesRead,
  _Inout_opt_ LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
);
```

However, when I try

```
  let output = ctypes.char.array(1024);
  let isRead = readFile(hFile, output, 1024, bytesWritten.address())
```

I get

> JPM [error]   Message: TypeError: can't pass ctypes.char.array(1024)
>   to argument 2 of int32_t ReadFile(void*, char*, uint32_t, void**)

**More attempts.**

```
  let output = ctypes.char.array(1024);
  let isRead = readFile(hFile, output.ptr, 1024, bytesWritten.address())
```

> JPM [error]   Message: TypeError: can't pass
>   ctypes.char.array(1024).ptr to argument 2 of int32_t ReadFile(void*,
>   char*,  uint32_t, void**

```
  let output = ctypes.char.array(1024);
  let isRead = readFile(hFile, output.address(), 1024, bytesWritten.address())
```

> JPM [error]   Message: TypeError: output.address is not a function

```
  let output = ctypes.char.ptr;
  let isRead = readFile(hFile, output, 1024, bytesWritten.address())
```

> JPM [error]   Message: TypeError: can't pass ctypes.char.ptr to
>   argument 2 of int32_t ReadFile(void*, char*, uint32_t, v oid**)

Answer (score 1):

This made it work

```
  let outputType = ctypes.char.array(1024);
  let output = outputType();
  let isRead = readFile(hFile, output, 1024, bytesWritten.address(), null);
```